# How to say that a room has a lot of flies?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, usage

I want to say this line to someone that room has a lot of flies. How can i say this ?

Comment: You can say it is _full of flies_, it is _infested with flies_, it is _fly-ridden_. Or you can say it ahas a lot of flies.

Comment: Why does the room have so many flies? We might be able to suggest better words if we know more details.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName supposed the room is dirty so it has a lot of flies.

Answer (score 1):

You practically answered your own question: "You (sure) have a lot of flies in your room!"

When you add *sure* to an observation, it means something like "I have to say" or "I noticed," and may express a bit of annoyance, but not necessarily - that depends on the context and your intonation, etc.